# Not able to find packages in iso for many standard elf binaries including hostname, bash, dash, login

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dpkg, hostname

I am given with VM disk and ISO image. I need to make sure all the ELF binaries on VM disk are part of given ISO image. In-order to do that I pickup each binary on VM and look into all the .deb, .udeb packages in ISO file to see if it is packaged in any of those packages. While doing that I found very basic binaries, such as hostname, login etc. are not part of any of the packages in ISO. Is/are there any compressed file/s I am not looking into for these binaries?

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks for your response. Packages for those binaries are not available in ISO. I might be missing someing while looking in to ISO. for example: Binary /bin/hostname is available on VM created using ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso. Package for that is hostname_3.15ubuntu1_amd64.deb or hostname*.deb However, when I mount ISO and run 'find . -name *hostname*' I do not find any package.

Comment: Still not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps if you were to [edit] your post to indicate how you came up with your list it would help us help you! I believe this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in which you are asking about the results of your attempted solution rather than your root problem.

Comment: I believe that with sopme study you may find [this useful](https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php)

Comment: Maybe your assumption that everything is "from" a deb package is wrong -- your source of the "missing" files may just be the compressed filesystem.

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes, that is what I am looking for. Other than deb packages  what are the other package files (or compressed files) I should be looking for?

Comment: @ElderGeek For now, lets forget about the list. Let me try to simplify. What I am looking for is here: I have given with VM disk and ISO image. I need to make sure all the ELF binaries on VM disk are part of given ISO image. In-order to do that I pickup each binary on VM and look into all the .deb, .udeb packages in ISO file to see if it is packaged in any of those packages. While doing that I found few of the binaries available on VM are not part of any of the packages in ISO. List is not complete. I hope I have simplified it.

Comment: @Alpesh the proper way to clarify your question is by [edit] of your post. Comments can be deleted at any time for various reasons. Thank you.

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks for suggestion. I will edit the post.

Comment: @ElderGeek I have edited the post. My question is closed. How do I reopen it? Sorry, for such basic questions. I am new bee to this blog site.

Comment: The information that you seek is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) However, in this case it appears that you already have an accepted answer so I'm not sure what new answers would provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look under the casper directory on the ISO, and there is a file filesystem.squashfs.  This contains the "missing" files, and there is another filesystem.manifest to identify their originating packages and versions.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I am out on vacation. I will check it out once back in office next week. I will update you as on the same. Thanks

Comment: I could not wait until next week and tried it today. Look like I find all the binaries in ISO. Thanks a lot.